# Material with several colors for mesh in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, mesh, unreal-engine4

I have a mesh presented as UProceduralMeshComponent. Also I have a set of colors: one color for each vertex of this mesh.

I'm looking for a way to create a dynamic material in which all these colors will be and they will correspond to the coordinates of the vertices. It should look something like this:

[image]

Does anybody know the way how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`UProceduralMeshComponent::CreateMeshSection`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Plugins/ProceduralMeshComponent/UProceduralMeshComponent/CreateMeshSection/1/index.html) accepts an array of vertex colors. Pass an array of colors for each vertex and use a [VertexColors](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UI/LevelEditor/Modes/MeshPaintMode/VertexColor/MaterialSetup/Color/index.html) node in your material.